# Graphics API and double precision

Tags: precision

For scientific reasons, we have to use doubles in our shaders. We don't need to talk about trying to store data in floating point numbers and so on.
I know there is special GPU hardware for double precision to work faster than on regular GPUs.

We are writing some GPU based software that should work for standard GPUs (2015 - now).
Do OpenGL, Vulkan, CUDA and OpenCL support double precision?
In the case of using a GPU that is not designed to use doubles, do the APIs emulate them?
So would such software work on these hardware systems?

Comment: GLSL supports doubles in the language to check hardware support in OpenGL look up  the "GL_ARB_gpu_shader_fp64" extension. To check hardware support in Vulkan check the physical device limits `VkPhysicalDeviceProperties deviceProperties.limits.shaderDoublePrecision` Support is generally binary. If you do run into a driver that is somehow emulating doubles the performance will be blatantly clear.

Comment: Why would OpenGL or Vulkan benefit from double precision ? When it comes to display, 4 digits accuracy can be overkill.

Comment: @YvesDaoust the doubles are used for physical accuracy... Not for displaying.

Comment: Why even debate the efficacy of existing functionality? The question is about if it is supported, which it is.

Comment: Of course, so what's the need to be accurate in OpenGL or Vulkan ? Your screen resolution most probably does not exceed 4K pixels.

Comment: GPU's are used for more then just generating pixel colors. Scientific applications can/should take advantage of all that floating point power and they often require high precision to get reasonable results. Take a look at the "Frontier" super computer, at ~1.7 *exaflops* it uses GPU's to generate all that floating point power.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double-precision operations have been a requirement of desktop OpenGL and GLSL since 4.0. GPUs don't "emulate" double precision, but that doesn't mean they operate at full-speed either. As with most things, Vulkan is a bit more fine-grained, as SPIR-V requires you to use the `Float64` if you want to use them, and the implementation must support the `shaderFloat64` feature.

Comment: So the program would run on any machine which supports opengl 4.0